# Cant Show Data on Info Window GoogleMap that contain text or string in JavaScript Variable with php text on the query

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have some problem, i want show data on the infowindow that using GoogleMap API, that i queries from Database and call with php script and save on Javascript text.
Here's My Code

```
var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle Polygon</b><br>';
var infoo = <?php
include_once("koneksi.php");
$sql3="SELECT a.Informasi from asset a where ID_Asset='AST01'";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
$data3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
Print $data3[0];
?>;
contentString += 'Informasi: <br>' + infoo + '<br>';
infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
infoWindow.open(map);
```

When i change query that return number data it work, but it doesnt' work if return text or string data.
Anyone Help

Comment: What does the html/javascript that the browser is rendering look like ('view source')?

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating the `<?php ?`> for `var infoo =` in quotes?

Comment: i already did what you say @elzaer and it work :D Thank You Very Much Broo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for consistency (and so the answer can be marked):

```
var infoo = "<?php
    include_once("koneksi.php");
    $sql3="SELECT a.Informasi from asset a where ID_Asset='AST01'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
    $data3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
    Print $data3[0];
?>";
```